# Get a json object based on textarea content

Tags: php

I'm trying to get the values of a text area and create a json object based on that .

The textarea looks like this:

```
<textarea name="msisdn" wrap="physical">
51971855080
51971855081
51971855082
</textarea>
```

The dynamic parts are "messId" and "destAddr" the other ones will be replaced with php variables received from a form like this way:

```
$str_obj_json='{
"method":"SUBMIT","params":{
"batchType":"submit",
"batchId":"'.$batch.'",
"origAddr":"550",
"origTon":2,
"userData":"'.$sms.'",
"submits":
  [
   {
   "messId":"mess127_009",
   "destAddr":"51971855080"},
   {
   "messId":"mess127_010",
   "destAddr":"51971855081"},
   {
   "messId":"mess127_011",
   "destAddr":"51971855082"},
  ]
}
}';
```

How to create this part dynamically ?:

```
  "submits":
  [
   {
   "messId":"mess127_009",
   "destAddr":"51971855080"},
   {
   "messId":"mess127_010",
   "destAddr":"51971855081"},
   {
   "messId":"mess127_011",
   "destAddr":"51971855082"},
  ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `json_encode()`:

```
$submits = array();

for (...) {
    $submits[] = array('messId' => ..., 'destAddr' => ...);
}

$jsonString = json_encode(array('submits' => $submits);
```

It converts PHP arrays into JSON notation. So you can create your array dynamically as desired, and then encode it afterwards.

As for using the values from the `textarea`: Just split the corresponding `$_POST` data into lines using `split("\n", $_POST['msisdn'])`

Comment: Based on lethal-guitar (many thanks) this is what i did:
<code>
<?php  
$var_messid=explode("\r\n", $_POST['sms']);  
$var_msisdn=explode("\r\n", $_POST['msisdn']);
$submits = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < 3; ++$i) 
{
    $submits[] = array('messId' => $var_messid[$i],'destAddr' => $var_msisdn[$i]);
}
$jsonString = json_encode(array('submits' => $submits));
print_r($jsonString);
?>´

Comment: Whooaaa that's a lot of code. Please put it in your answer (via editing).